Boot Order Modification on Raspberry Pi Zero 2W (USB -> SDcard)
I have an RPI Zero 2W and I have a question regarding booting (bootloader, boot order).
First of all, I've set up USB booting using an SD card on the Raspberry Pi. What I want to do is to change the boot order so that the USB boots when both the SD card and USB are connected. Currently, the SD card boots first, preventing USB booting. So, I've been trying to change the boot order.
The method I've tried involves modifying the cmdline.txt on the SD card to change the partition ID to USB, allowing booting from USB. However, this method has the drawback that it cannot switch back to booting from the SD card.
Is there a way to change the boot order on the Raspberry Pi Zero 2W when both the SD card and USB are connected, without resorting to the method mentioned above? (Raspberry Pi 4 has EEPROM, making it easier to change the boot order, but the Zero does not, which complicates things.)
After 2-3 years of booting from the SD card, failures become frequent. This is likely due to the lifespan of the SD card. I'm curious how others have dealt with this issue. I want to address this problem and automatically switch to booting from USB.
I would really appreciate your help.

Welcome. "After 2-3 years of booting from the SD card, failures become frequent. This is likely due to the lifespan of the SD card. " -> Not unreasonable, but also leaves lots of  wiggle room for an XY problem.

I'm aware it's likely due to the lifespan of the SD card. Before its lifespan ends, I want to boot via USB. So, I'd like to change the boot order

I'm just gently introducing the possibility that it is not because of SD card problems -- "must be sd card corruption" is a kind of off-hand, throw-up-my-hands diagnosis that is much abused amongst Pi users and tends to be contagious amongst them.  So you might consider asking a question describing in detail the failures to see if anyone has any insight into that.   Problems like this do tend to be alleviated with a fresh install, so moving to USB might help regardless of cause unless you just duplicate the existing system by making a straight copy.

Not sure if it works on the zero or zero 2, but the Pi 1 and 2 could not boot from USB directly - however, all you need is bootcode.bin on the sd-card - this is correct as of bullseye, have not tried bookworm on my pi 1's - but then, bookworm isn't even recommended for anything before a pi 4
